# Things can only save to "Windows" file, else 0 disk space so it won't save

Tags: wine, downloads

I'm trying to save downloads (programs such as sublime text, or images/music, other downloads) and it tells me I have 0 disk space, unless I save to Windows (I downloaded Ubuntu 16 yesterday through a usb and did a complete system reset to remove all programs and files, this cleaned up storage space but now I can only access Ubuntu not both linux & Windows).

I don't know how to use the terminal yet (other than copying and pasting). So can someone tell me to make it so that all files from browser (I've already installed wine) or from Ubuntu software save automatically to the path of "windows" or if you can tell me how to clear up the place of whatever path it's already taking that would be great too.

I'm not too tech savvy so please try to use simple non-high-tech words and explanations.

[storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnmE7.png)

[image: disk usage analyser]

Comment: Please copy and paste the texts from your terminal in the first image and add that to your post. Image of text aren't encouraged.

Comment: You gave the Ubuntu root partition only 6GB. From [Ubuntu 16.04 system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements): `a netbook with an 8 GB SSD will work well although there wont be much room for saving stuff directly onto the drive so cloud storage services could help a lot`. I would propose increasing the disk space allocated to \.